# Export / Import ECMASCRIPT 6 Class with JSON

Tags: json, ecmascript-6

This is all using ecmascript 6; Say I have a class

```
class Hero {
    constructor(id,name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

And I want to have create an array of object of that type of class:

```
var HEROES = [
  { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" },
  { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" },
  { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" },
  { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" },
  { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" },
  { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" }
];
```

Is there a way to do this besides manually parsing the array and then doing New Hero() for each element? It would be nice to be able to do something like `HEROES[] = hero.jsonExport()` and then later `var = hero.jsonImport(HEROES[i])`. I've been looking around but without using Typescript this doesn't seem particularly easy. Am I missing something easy?
Thanks!
-Eric

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `HEROS.map(({id, name}) => new Hero(id, name))` ?

Comment: Add a `static fromJSON({id, name}) { return new this(id, name); }` method to your class and then use `HEROES.map(Hero.fromJSON)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange to want to import from a specific array instance - especially given that the order could change. It would probably be better to export a factory function which creates a `new Hero` based off the criteria:

```
class Hero {
    constructor(id,name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
}

const HEROES = [
  { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" },
  { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" },
  { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" },
  { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" },
  { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" },
  { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" }
];

export default function createHero(index) {
    const hero = HEROES[index];
    return new Hero(hero.id,hero.name);
}
```

And the caller:

```
import createHero from "./hero";
const hero1 = createHero(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, so it would have to be done one-at-a-time in an iterative manner then correct? There is no way to have the entire array of HEROES be an array of array of Hero objects?

Comment: @ehiller: Well, you can of course start with `const HEROES = [new Hero(11, "Mr. Nice"), new Hero(12, "Narco"), …]` right away, but your question asks for JSON